# Not able to pass JSON data using FETCH

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, express, fetch

I am having an API Service build on node js running on port 3001 and a web UI using REACT & running on port 3000. I have to POST details from Web page to the API in JSON Format. I am able to hit the API, however I could not get the JSON on the API. Its being received as {}. However the API is working fine from postman.

Could some one please share light on where i am missing.

```
Source code of API 

const util = require('util')
const request = require("request");
const express = require('express')

const app = express();
const port = 3001

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: false}));
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { json } = require('express/lib/response');

app.post('/PostPatronDetailsone',(req,res) => {
    
    async function run() {
        try {       
            console.log('Request received from REACT ONE');
            // parse application/json
            app.use(bodyParser.json())
            console.log(req.body);
            
            // Respond back
            res.send('Transaction Sent');
        } finally {
            // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        }
    }
    run().catch(console.dir);    
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server is listening at port ' + port));
```

```
Code Snippet of Web making the HTTP POST

import React from 'react';

class Signup extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          postId: null
        };

    }

    async componentDidMount() {
      // Simple POST request with a JSON body using fetch
      let payload = {'first_name': 'TEST' };
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

      const requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'no-cors',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept':'application/json' },
          body: data,
          redirect: 'follow'
      };
    
      var response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/PostPatronDetailsone', requestOptions);
      var data1 = await response.json();
      var data2 = data1.text();
      alert(data2);
      //this.setState({ postId: data1.insertedid });             

    }

    render() {
        const { postId } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className="card text-center m-3">
          <h5 className="card-header">Simple POST Request</h5>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Signup;
```

```
Console Output of API Service 
Server is listening at port 3001
Request received from REACT ONE
{}
Request received from REACT ONE
{}
```

Comment: why you need `var data = new FormData();
      data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );`, Why just you cannot send json payload if you are doing same in next steps

Comment: Also did you tried calling your API externally with curl or postman?
Also remove `app.use(bodyParser.json())` from that function and try calling api externally

Answer (score 0):

It is because you send formData, instead stringify the object and send it to body like this:

```
    async componentDidMount() {
  // Simple POST request with a JSON body using fetch
  let payload = {first_name: 'TEST' };

  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept':'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload ),
      redirect: 'follow'
  };

  var response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/PostPatronDetailsone', requestOptions);
  var data1 = await response.json();
  var data2 = data1.text();
  alert(data2);
  //this.setState({ postId: data1.insertedid });             

}
```

Comment: From controller also remove
   app.use(bodyParser.json())

Comment: Hi Paiman, Thanks for your response. I had tried the same suggestion. However still could not get the JSON on the API. Could you please share if i am missing any other.

Comment: @Veky let me check your code. I will comment again.

Comment: try new code which I modified.

Comment: for now remove async from run function inside API because there is nothing async there!

Comment: He is using .catch at end, so async will be needed , else it will throw undefined error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined
`

Comment: I have tried it also. Still getting the JSON as {}

Comment: I know but while using async you must have at least one promise inside that like reading data from the database. Believe me, just remove async, catch, finally for now and console.log the body.

Comment: @PaimanRasoli , I have removed the mentioned keywords on the API. Still the result is same. . Code snippet is below.  ' app.post('/PostPatronDetailsone',(req,res) => {
    
    function run() {
   
  
   console.log('Request received from REACT ONE');
   // parse application/json
   console.log(req.body);
   
   // Respond back
   res.send('Transaction Sent');
 }
    run();    
});'

Comment: console.log the body outside the run function.

Comment: and also => const app = express();
i don't see this code in your API!!!!

Comment: @PaimanRasoli. Its already there. Sorry, I missed to include the statement in the code snippet while raising the question.  '
const app = express();
const port = 3001'

Comment: inspect the browser navigate to the network tab see which status are you getting from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code as follows:

```
let payload = {'first_name': 'TEST' };
fetch('http://localhost:3001/PostPatronDetailsone',{
  body:JSON.stringify(payload),
  method:'post',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  
}).then((res)=>res.json()).then((data)=>console.log(data));
```

And from controller in backend remove that line as you are already using express.json() which is equivalent to that line:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // remove it
```

Comment: Hi Asad, Thanks for your response. I had tried the mentioned suggestion. However still could not get the JSON on the API. Could you please share if i am missing any other.

Comment: I have changed the code please check it

Comment: @Venky Does it fulfill your requirement now?

Comment: I am still getting the same. In API, i could not get the JSON being passed from REACT.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 key problems here:

1. You are posting a FormData object (which gets converted to a multipart/form-data encoding) and not JSON
2. You are setting `no-cors` mode which causes the browser to silently discard any instructions to do anything that would require CORS permission (such as setting the `application/json` content-type or reading the response)
3. There won't be a `text()` method on anything parsed from JSON

---

```
const data = {'first_name': 'TEST' };
const payload = JSON.stringify(data)

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept':'application/json' },
    body: payload,
    redirect: 'follow'
};

const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/PostPatronDetailsone', requestOptions);
const parsed_json = await response.json();
console.log(parsed_json);
```

You will also need to change the server-side code to grant permission to the JavaScript to read the response and send the JSON formatted request. Use the `cors` module for that.

```
app.use(cors());
```

---

Also note that body parsing middleware needs to be set up when the application starts and **not** in the middle of a route. The body-parser module has been obsoleted as Express has its features built-in now.

The following is good:

> ```
> app.use(express.json());
> ```

The following is bad:

> ```
> const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
> ```

and

> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.json())
> ```

---

Your route code doesn't need to be any more complex than:

```
app.post('/PostPatronDetailsone', async (req,res) => {
    console.log('Request received from REACT ONE');    
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json('Transaction Sent');
});
```

Note that since you are trying to parse the response as JSON in the client side code, I've had to change `send` to `json` so that the server outputs JSON instead of plain text.